# how can i checked checkbox array data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

If a student has Multiple courses, the checkboxes are not checked

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($course_qry)){ ?>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' <?php if (in_array($course_fetch['id'], explode(',' $re['course']))) echo "checked='checked'" ?> />
<?php } ?>
```

// 1 checked, 0 unchecked from db structure

Hope this will work...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing multiple wrong things.

First you are checking course with id while course is a comma separated list. use

```
if(in_array(id, explode(',', course)));
```

Second you should not use value coming from get/post directly in your query it's a huge security risk